# return file response in laravel not working

Tags: laravel-5

I'm using laravel 5.2 , I've used response()->file()  function to return file. On localhost it is working as expected but on live server file is being downloaded automatically (with no extension). But i wish to open it instead of downlod. Anyone can help?

Here is my code:

---

public function returnFile($slug)

```
{$file = Mixes::where('id_name,'=',$slug)->get()->first();
 return response()->file('./path/to/file/'.$file->name);}
```

---

Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You'll need to add header to your response.
Response with header example:

```
$response->header('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
```

Simple example:

```
$file = File::get($file);
   $response = Response::make($file, 200);
   $response->header('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
   return $response;
```

Then the file will display in your browser window.

This solution will work with files **pdf,docx,doc,xls**.

Hope it will help!

Comment: return response()->file('./media/mixes/'.$details->mix,['Content-Disposition: inline;filename="'.$details->mix.'"']);

Comment: That's great that you've found the rest of the solution!